# how to select rows from table A based on json column in table B

Tags: json, postgresql

I have two tables.

Table A has the metadata with a string name column and a json column which stores mac_ids like the following

```
   name    |   ids
---------------------------
  site1    | {"type1": ["id1", "id2"], "type2": ["id3", "id4"]}
  site2    | {"type1": ["id5", "id6"], "type3": ["id7", "id8"], "type4"...}
   ...     |  ...
```

Table B has only the id and the data like so

```
   id  |   data
-----------------
   id1 | 1.23
   id2 | 3.45
  ...  | ...
```

I want to create a query to select rows from Table B based on a site name and an id type in Table A.

For example, I want to select all rows in B where ids are in site1, type1.

Assume that we want to find ids from only the last record of table A where the name is site1.

Here is a query that I tried that didn't work

```
SELECT * FROM table_b
WHERE id IN ( SELECT ids -> 'type1' 
               FROM table_a 
               WHERE name = 'site1' 
               LIMIT 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ids -> 'type1'` results in a `JSON` value, which might be an array but cannot be used with the `IN` operator. You would first [need to turn that into a Postgres array](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/54283/188406):

```
SELECT * FROM table_b
WHERE id = ANY(ARRAY(
    SELECT el
    FROM table_a, LATERAL json_array_elements_text(ids -> 'type1') el
    WHERE name = 'site1'));
```

([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0277dde93571a04cd8a447fb022d1230), [weird alternative](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c261716e07e906e643b26826faf31604))

Alternatively, you can try some of the fancy new [Postgres 12 json path functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html):

```
SELECT table_b.*
FROM table_b JOIN table_a ON jsonb_path_match(
                               ids::jsonb,
                               '$.type1[*] == $id',
                               jsonb_build_object('id', id))
WHERE name = 'site1';
```

([Online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a6a9634daf07c16aa011589ecd3445fb))

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Also really appreciate your reference to the detailed [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array)